# What is the most efficient way to read a large file in chunks without loading the entire file in memory at once?

Tags: file, io, rust

What is the most efficient general purpose way of reading "large" files (which may be text or binary), without going into `unsafe` territory? I was surprised how few relevant results there were when I did a web search for "rust read large file in chunks".

For example, one of my use cases is to calculate an MD5 checksum for a file using `rust-crypto` (the `Md5` module allows you to add `&[u8]` chunks iteratively).

Here is what I have, which seems to perform slightly better than some other methods like `read_to_end`:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{self, BufRead, BufReader},
};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    const CAP: usize = 1024 * 128;
    let file = File::open("my.file")?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::with_capacity(CAP, file);

    loop {
        let length = {
            let buffer = reader.fill_buf()?;
            // do stuff with buffer here
            buffer.len()
        };
        if length == 0 {
            break;
        }
        reader.consume(length);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Why do you have closure for fill_buf? I had issue that this closure fixes. Could you please point me to the right direction.

Comment: @Townsheriff, do you mean, why is `reader.fill_buf()?` in a block (`let length = { ... }`)? If so, it is because the borrow checker back in 2016 was not as sophisticated as it is now. If I were to put the `fill_buf` and `consume` in the same scope, rustc would complain `cannot borrow \`reader\` as mutable more than once at a time`. `fill_buf` returns a reference to the underlying reader, so putting it in a shorter lived scope could be what is solving your issue.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I encountered in todays stable rust version. Big thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you can write code more efficient than that.  `fill_buf` on a `BufReader` over a `File` is [basically just a straight call to `read(2)`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libstd/io/buffered.rs#L246-L257).

That said, `BufReader` isn't really a useful abstraction when you use it like that; it would probably be less awkward to just call `file.read(&mut buf)` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought `BufReader` was being useful for me since it resized the buffer for me when I got to the end of the reader, but I just realized that's pretty trivial...

Comment: *since it resized the buffer* — I doubt that it resizes the buffer, but the slice is presumably shortened to reflect the number of bytes read. But you are right that the return value of `Read::read` tells you how much of the buffer is valid. It's **very important** to use that, otherwise you can get into a problem like Heartbleed where a buffer is reused with old content! That might be a good reason to use `BufReader`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I meant "shortened the length of the buffer".

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, I don't know if it is wrong but it worked perfectly for me, still don't know if it is the correct way tho..

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> 
{
    const FNAME: &str = "LargeFile.txt";
    const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 1024; // bytes read by every loop iteration.
    let mut limit: usize = (1024 * 1024) * 15; // How much should be actually read from the file..
    let mut f = File::open(FNAME)?;
    let mut buffer = [0; CHUNK_SIZE]; // buffer to contain the bytes.

    // read up to 15mb as the limit suggests..
    loop {
        if limit > 0 {
            // Not finished reading, you can parse or process data.
            let _n = f.read(&mut buffer[..])?;

            for bytes_index in 0..buffer.len() {
               print!("{}", buffer[bytes_index] as char);
            }
            limit -= CHUNK_SIZE;
        } else {
            // Finished reading..
            break;
        }
    }    
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of read a large file in chunks without loading the entire file into memory at once.

See:

[rust-cookbook](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/cryptography/hashing.html)

new_file.txt can be a large file.

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufReader, Read, Write}, 
    error::Error,
};

const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 5;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // create new_file.txt
    let path = "new_file.txt";
    let mut output = File::create(path)?;
    writeln!(output, "We will generate this text")?;
    writeln!(output, "Line 2 bla bla bla")?;
    writeln!(output, "Line 3 foo bar for bar")?;

    // read new_file.txt
    let input = File::open(path)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(input);
    read_file(reader)?;

    Ok(())
}

fn read_file<R: Read>(mut reader: R) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut buffer = [0_u8; BUFFER_SIZE];

    loop {
        let count = reader.read(&mut buffer)?;
        if count == 0 {
            break;
        }
        let string_slice = std::str::from_utf8(&buffer[..count])?;

        // Read BUFFER_SIZE bytes in each loop
        // Change print! to println!, to see the result.
        
        print!("{string_slice}");

        //println!("{string_slice}");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

See [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=79f9e868af36850252ce960da71349db).