# How do I read and process N lines of a file at a time in Rust?

Tags: io, rust

I would like to read N lines of a file at a time, possibly using `itertools::Itertools::chunks`.

When I do:

```
for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
   ... // this is processing one line at a time
}
```

... although I'm buffering input, I am not processing the buffer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079342/most-efficient-way-to-read-large-file-in-chunks

Comment: @Sid why do you think the duplicate apply ? In your dup there is no mention of lines processing.

Comment: "possibly using itertools::Itertools::chunks" why not didn't you not try to use it ?  "although I'm buffering input, I am not processing the buffer." ??????

Comment: @Stargateur, hence the 'Possible duplicate'...

Comment: @Sid Still if you propose it you **should** have some through about why you think it's a duplicate, but ok you just proposed it without strong feeling that ok.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`chunks()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks) from itertools:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.0
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let n = 3;

    for lines in &stdin.lock().lines().chunks(n) {
        for (i, line) in lines.enumerate() {
            println!("Line {}: {:?}", i, line);
        }
    }
}
```